# Android java Timer for notification

Tags: java, android, timer, notifications

I am building an app in java for android. For that I have a calendar. It want to make it like this way: Every time at 8 o'clock, the timer should check if there is a event for the next day. If there is one it should notify the user.

The notification is not the problem, but how do I time the "trigger-point" 8 o'clock?

In the tutorials on youtube, they always have a button as a trigger, but in my case, I cannot decide when the Timer starts like that :(.

Here is my try: (I wanted to get the last epoch numbers and compare it to the actual time)

```
timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                int time = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.e("Timer:", "Tick");

                if(new String("" + time).endsWith("" + 18980000)){
                    createAndDisplayNotification("Hello there!");
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

Hope you guys can help me... ;).

Comment: For earth's sake, please don't use `endsWith` to compare time. Use `>=`. You may use `AlarmManager` to schedule jobs to run at specified time.

Comment: I cant do that because than I would compare also the day and the year and so on, but this is nothing that is interesting for me! (I mean your >=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a timer in android is not a good idea because it may kill by the os 
better thing to do is to use  alarmManager class which is available in android

here is android tutorial which describes how to schedule task with alarm manager :

https://en.proft.me/2017/05/7/scheduling-operations-alarmmanager-android/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` use the method [`timer.schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date)):

> Schedules the specified task for execution **at the specified time**. If the time is in the past, the task is scheduled for immediate execution.

So you can schedule it exactly at 8 o' clock without needs to check it every second.